# Restangular use save()

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm playing with Restangular and I want to make a call to .save() to update or create an entity. From Restangular [github page](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) I can see that it is possible to update or create a new account. But if there are no accounts on the server I get method does not exists. (firstAccount is undefined)

```
Restangular.all('accounts').getList().then(function(accounts) {
  var firstAccount = accounts[0];
  firstAccount.title = "New title"
  // PUT /accounts/123. Save will do POST or PUT accordingly
  firstAccount.save();
});
```

My question is how do I make firstAccount a restangular object that will go to the correct url (POST /accounts) when I call firstAccount.save() if there are no accounts in the response?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to create a new element, you may restangularize it:

```
var account = {
    title: 'New Title'
};
var restangularAccount = Restangular.restangularizeElement(null, account, 'accounts');
restangularAccount.save();
```

That will do an HTTP POST to /accounts